# Using Anaconda, is a messy base root going to be a problem in the long term?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I generally used to use Python for number crunching, but recently decided to learn more dev aspects of the language (e.g. developing apps).

I only recently realised you could create environments in Anaconda (through that 'Environments' tab), and previously just pip installed everything onto my base root environment.

Reading further into it, some people don't seem to recommend installing certain things onto base root. Will I potentially have issues by continuing on with my potentially messy base root environment? Will it potentially affect other environments, or are they completely separate?

If it's going to be an issue, how can I clean my base root environment up?

Comment: _previously just pip installed everything onto my base root environment._ Using pip can also be problematic, see https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment. _Will I potentially have issues by continuing on with my potentially messy base root environment?_ Yes, absolutely. If you take a look through the conda and anaconda tags, you can find plenty of people with issues which stem from that. _Will it potentially affect other environments, or are they completely separate?_ Hopefully not, although Conda itself might be affected, I'm not sure.

Comment: _I only recently realised you could create environments in Anaconda (through that 'Environments' tab)_ Anaconda doesn't manage environments, Conda does. The tab you're referring to is likely in Anaconda Navigator, which is just a GUI for Anaconda. I would recommend reading [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/) informative article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have exactly the right idea.

#### I would install from scratch using Miniconda.

It's an initial pain, but I would remove all trace of your current Anaconda installation and do a fresh install from [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). Then always create new environments as needed, such as one per project, and almost never touch your root environment. I typically install packages needed to build projects in my root.

#### Generating environment files

Anaconda is great for ensuring a reproducible build. You can list out your project's requirements in an `environment.yml` file and recover from that at any point.

For example, the start of one of mine is below. I try to list out my dependencies manually.
To build from this environment, I can just run `conda env create --force --file kaleforge.yml`.

By the way, I *highly* recommend using Conda-Forge instead of the default channel! It just has more packages. You're less likely to have version conflicts or versions writing over each other.

```
name: kaleforge
channels:
  - conda-forge

dependencies:

  # @ python
 - python>=3.7

  # @ framework
 - pip>=20.0

  # @ test
 - hypothesis>=5.8
 - pytest>=5.4

  # interactive
 - jupyterlab>=2.0
 - ipympl>=0.5.6

  # @ strict
 - rdkit>=2020.03
 - cryptography>=2.8,<3.0
 - cycler>=0.10.0,<1.0
 - h5py>=2.10,<3.0
 - imageio>=2.8,<3.0
 - joblib>=0.14,<1.0
 - matplotlib>=3.2,<4.0
 - natsort>=7.0,<8.0
 - numba>=0.48,<1.0
 - numpy>=1.18,<1.19
 - pandas>=1.0.3,<2.0
 - pillow>=7.0,<8.0
 - scipy>=1.4,<2.0
 - scikit-image>=0.16,<1.0
 - scikit-learn>=0.21.0,<1.0
 # @ pip 
 - pip
    - librosa>=0.7.2,<1.0
    # - put other packages here that are only on PyPi
```

Comment: I see. I guess it'll be painful at first, but at least I'll be starting from a good base.

Are you recommending Miniconda specifically because it's stripped down version of Anaconda and I have more freedom to choose which modules to include in my environment?

Also, in a slight tangent to my original question, is creating an environment via the 'Environments' tab in Anaconda the same as creating a virtual environment? If not, which should I be using?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly why. Minoconda also just less bulk, so fewer packages will need to be downloaded an updated. It's also an immediate reminder when I'm accidentally using the environment: The packages I expect just aren't installed.

I don't use the graphical tool, but I definitely imagine it's the same.

Comment: @pyman Don't worry, uninstalling Anaconda is likely the most painful part!

Comment: @pyman _Are you recommending Miniconda specifically because it's stripped down version of Anaconda and I have more freedom to choose which modules to include in my environment?_ It's also that if you're using conda-forge, which is a good suggestion, then all the packages in Anaconda will go completely unused.

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent, but I recently learned about [Python Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) and about standard Python packaging after struggling with some Anaconda problems. I've been using it on top of an anaconda environment. I put a [template here](https://github.com/dmyersturnbull/tyrannosaurus) after some pain.

Comment: @DouglasMyers-Turnbull I've also been hearing about Poetry, I'll check out the template :)

Comment: Strongly agree. The **base** env should really be restricted to just the stuff that `conda` (the Python package) needs to work and otherwise should be left alone. It's really an unfortunate design flaw that Anaconda colocates a monolith of packages in the **base**: it implicitly encourages users to use and install things in the **base** and this sets people up to break their Conda installs.

Comment: @merv I just wish the perils of base were made more obvious, I was thinking of contacting the people behind Conda about that.

Comment: @AMC [I proposed](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11336) they put the Conda infrastructure stuff in a protected env. One of the core devs said they've been working on developing Conda as a standalone. That would at least keep people from breaking their installs.